# Freebsd how detect ethernet loopback on interface

Tags: freebsd, ethernet

I have network based on stupid hubs.

And freebsd router in center of this network.

Today i see in 'systat -vmstat'  :
 Interrupts 8005 em1:rx 0

That was a loop on one hub.

Is there any way to detect this and email me if this happent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either institute sufficient administrative controls to prevent loops from being formed or replace your hubs with switches capable of running spanning tree.

Comment: Yep, i am sure, that will work. But for now i searching pure-freebsd solution.

Comment: @KorjavinIvan: I doubt an email's going to make it out on a looped network.

Comment: no,no. em0 connect to upstream and can send email, its not a problem